# Why does SyntaxNode.ReplaceNode change the SyntaxTree options?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to replace nodes within a syntax tree in Roslyn, and it's just about working, but with an annoyance which feels it *shouldn't* be a problem.

The syntax tree is generated from a script, and I want the result to be a script-based syntax tree too - but for some reason, replacing a node in the tree creates a new syntax tree with changed options: the `Kind` becomes `Regular` instead of `Script`. That's fixable with `SyntaxTree.WithRootAndOptions` but it feels like I'm doing something wrong if I need to call that.

Sample program:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Script script = CSharpScript.Create("Console.WriteLine(\"Before\")",
            ScriptOptions.Default.AddImports("System"));

        var compilation = script.GetCompilation();
        var tree = compilation.SyntaxTrees.Single();

        var after = SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(
            SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression,
            SyntaxFactory.Literal("After"));

        var root = tree.GetRoot();
        var before = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<LiteralExpressionSyntax>().Single();
        var newRoot = root.ReplaceNode(before, after);
        var fixedTree = newRoot.SyntaxTree.WithRootAndOptions(newRoot, tree.Options);

        Console.WriteLine(newRoot);                         // Console.WriteLine("After")
        Console.WriteLine(tree.Options.Kind);               // Script
        Console.WriteLine(newRoot.SyntaxTree.Options.Kind); // Regular
        Console.WriteLine(fixedTree.Options.Kind);          // Script
    }
}
```

(Output is in comments.)

Is this workaround actually correct, or is there some different way I should be replacing the node in the tree?

Comment: The language version also changes. You have to explicitly specify if you want a C# 5 syntax tree. I also used the `.WithRootAndOptions()` and never had issues with that.

Comment: My gut is saying this is a bug...

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: I'm glad you're the one to say that - I certainly didn't want to :) (But yes, it feels like it to me too.)

Comment: the culprit is this block https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Syntax/CSharpSyntaxTree.cs#L344-L357. When a `SyntaxTree` is obtained via a property of a `SytntaxNode`, a syntax tree with default parse options (`CSharpParseOptions.Default`) is created

Comment: @FilipW: Worse still, line 339 has a mistake in the comment: "it's" instead of "its". Shocking.

Comment: @FilipW: But yes, that definitely looks like the code that's causing the problem. It's unclear whether or not it's intended behavior though. (I can't see why it would be, personally, but I know so little about the inner workings that my intuition can't be trusted here.)

Comment: @JasonMalinowski: Do you think it's worth filing a github issue about this?

Comment: @JonSkeet: definitely. I'm not aware of some reason to keep it this way, but maybe there is something and then that becomes a good answer for this.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/19741

Comment: Its not intended behavior for the default SyntaxTree of the rebuilt nodes to have the information from the original SyntaxTree.  That information was supplied by the parser based on the parse options used to parse the tree.  Once you've rewritten the tree, those options are no longer meaningful. You could have replaced the entire set of nodes parsed with entirely different options.

Answer (score 2):

When you replace nodes in a tree, you create a new sub-tree of nodes. Essentially, this new sub-tree is not contained within a SyntaxTree.  However, the SyntaxTree property on the node conjurs up a new one if you ever observe it.  At the time it does this, the original SyntaxTree is long gone, so its not possible to retain the parse options. Even if it were possible, retaining the options would be meaningless because you no longer have a tree produced by the parser.

The reason Roslyn creates this SyntaxTree is that so all sub-trees are technically contained within a SyntaxTree instance, so that Roslyn can associated diagnostics with it. This is useful if you use the SemanticModel's exploratory API's to attempt to bind & get semantic info for fragments of trees that are not currently part of the compilation.  The diagnostic reports the error and its location, which denotes the tree instance it is within.

Comment: "Even if it were possible, retaining the options would be meaningless because you no longer have a tree produced by the parser." That feels much more like a theoretical than practical reason though. Surely it's not an unusual scenario to say "I want this tree to be just like the other one, with this one node changed." I need to read the rest of your answer carefully when I have more time, but fundamentally this at least feels *awkward* in terms of API usage. It may have to be that way, but it's unfortunate IMO :(